# Parse JSON with mixed known/unknown fields in JAVA

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, pojo

I have simple JSON structure with known fields (A and B for example, typed as String) and some number of unknown fields (foo and bar, and maybe something other, or none of them, type unknown).

```
[
    {"A": "Value for A", B: "Value for B", "foo": "foo"},
    {"A": "Value for A", B: "Value for B", "bar": 13},
    {"A": "Value for A", B: "Value for B", "foo": "foo", "val": true}
]
```

I need to parse this JSON to POJO.
Jackson allows to parse this JSON to JsonNode, but JsonNode eats too much memory on huge amount of data.
Is there any solution to do that? I need to get instance of class like this:

```
class Simple
{
    public String A;
    public String B;
    public HashMap others;
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to change your JSON structure?

Comment: I getting this JSON as a string, so yes, if it can be effective. JSON is about 1 to 5 MB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use POJO with `@JsonAnySetter` method annotation. And you can actually even perform computations/optimisations in this method if you need them.

```
public class Simple {
    private String A;
    private String B;
    private Map other = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    // "any getter" needed for serialization    
    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map any() {
        return other;
    }

    // "any setter" needed for deserialization  
    @JsonAnySetter
    public void set(String name, Object value) {
        other.put(name, value);
    }

    // getter and setter for A and B
}
```